# Logic app xpath function return the result in encoded format

Tags: azure, xpath, azure-logic-apps

I have a an xml code that looks similar to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<part xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="payload">
    <process xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/CommonBaswareHTTPWrapperProvider/CommonBasware_HTTPWrapperProviderBPEL">
        <BaswareRequest xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/CommonBaswareHTTPWrapperProvider/BaswareRequest">
            <BOName>yy</BOName>
            <FileName>xx.xml</FileName>
            <Action>SEND</Action>
            <BOMessage>
                <DocumentElement xmlns="">
                    <Item>
                        <Text_1>123</Text_1>
                        <Text_2>123 CIO Office HOF</Text_2>
                        <Text_3>SWEDEN</Text_3>
                        <Text_4>3650</Text_4>
                        <Text_5>SWEDEN</Text_5>
                        <Text_6>True</Text_6>
                        <Text_EN />
                        <Active>True</Active>
                        <Company>001</Company>
                    </Item>
                </DocumentElement>
            </BOMessage>
        </BaswareRequest>
    </process>
</part>
```

I would Like to extract the element `BOMessage` with all its content and use it later in the code.

Inside the Logic App, I have created a `compose` action and written this code inside it:

```cs
xpath(xml(triggerBody()), '//*[local-name()="BOMessage"]')
```

The output of this action return a strange encoded code:

```json
[
  {
    "$content-type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
    "$content": "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"
  }
]
```

I tried to surround the `xpath` function with `xml()` function and `base64ToString()` and `decodeBase64()` but all of them are returning errors and doesn't seems to work.

Any idea for how to solve this issue?

Comment: The `$content` has the `BOMessage` element as base64 encoded string. You can verify that by using a online tool like [base64decode](https://www.base64decode.org/).

Comment: Without the Logic App definition I may not be able to give an exact answer, but you can try something like this;
`xml(base64ToString(first(outputs('Compose'))?['$content']))`.
Replace `Compose` with the name of your action that contains the encoded content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. When you try accessing the first element of the xpath output array, you'll be happy with the result. Try using the following in your 'Compose' action and you'll be OK:

```
xpath(xml(triggerBody()), '//*[local-name()="BOMessage"]')?[0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this little [0] is really helping. but what should I do if BOMessage was a real array and I want to have all the BOMessage elements in this array?

Comment: In this case each element of the array would represent an XML object. At the end of the day you'd be dealing with them individually e.g. by iterating the array. Generally, when you use those elements in other actions of your workflow, the Logic App engine will understand what they are and deal with them seamlessly. You shouldn't and won't need to focus on $content-type and $content (as suggested in the comments).